# Why is my function not affecting a button in tkinter?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I'm trying to make Tic Tac Toe in python using tkinter, but I'm running into an issue. I'm trying to make it so when you click on one of the squares, it displays whichever player's symbol on that square. However, with my current function `playerCheck`, nothing happens when I press them. I can't figure out why this is happening, so I would appreciate any help.

Keep in mind I am in no way finished.

```
import tkinter as tk

Player1 = "X"
Player2 = "O"
turn = None
playerNumber = None

def playerCheck(function):
    if turn == Player1:
        playerNumber = Player1
        function("white", playerNumber)

    elif turn == Player2:
        playerNumber = Player2
        function("white", playerNumber)

def topLeft(color, player):
    topL = tk.Button(text=player, fg="black", bg=color, height=5, width=10, command=lambda: playerCheck(topL)).grid(row=0,column=0)

def topMiddle(color, player):
    topM = tk.Button(text=player, fg="black", bg=color, height=5, width=10, command=lambda: playerCheck(topMiddle)).grid(row=0,column=1)

def topRight(color, player):
    topR = tk.Button(text=player, fg="black", bg=color, height=5, width=10, command=lambda: playerCheck(topRight)).grid(row=0,column=2)

def middleLeft(color, player):
    midL = tk.Button(text=player, fg="black", bg=color, height=5, width=10, command=lambda: playerCheck(middleLeft)).grid(row=1,column=0)

def middleMiddle(color, player):
    midM = tk.Button(text=player, fg="black", bg=color, height=5, width=10, command=lambda: playerCheck(middleMiddle)).grid(row=1,column=1)

def middleRight(color, player):
    midR = tk.Button(text=player, fg="black", bg=color, height=5, width=10, command=lambda: playerCheck(middleRight)).grid(row=1,column=2)

def bottomLeft(color, player):
    botL = tk.Button(text=player, fg="black", bg=color, height=5, width=10, command=lambda: playerCheck(bottomLeft)).grid(row=2,column=0)

def bottomMiddle(color, player):
    botM = tk.Button(text=player, fg="black", bg=color, height=5, width=10, command=lambda: playerCheck(bottomMiddle)).grid(row=2,column=1)

def bottomRight(color, player):
    botR = tk.Button(text=player, fg="black", bg=color, height=5, width=10, command=lambda: playerCheck(bottomRight)).grid(row=2,column=2)

def gameStart():
    topLeft("white", "")
    topMiddle("white", "")
    topRight("white", "")
    middleLeft("white", "")
    middleMiddle("white", "")
    middleRight("white", "")
    bottomLeft("white", "")
    bottomMiddle("white", "")
    bottomRight("white", "")
    turn = Player1

def Main():
    a = tk.Tk()
    a.title("Tick Tack Toe")
    a.geometry("250x250")
    gameStart()

    a.mainloop()
Main()
```

Comment: The argument to `playerCheck()` is supposed to be a function. But you're passing the button as the argument.

Comment: I think `playerCheck(topL)` should be `playerCheck(topLeft)`. `topL` is the button, `topLeft` is the function that places the button.

Comment: @Barmar I am using ```function``` just as a parameter word, I am trying just to grab the name of whatever function the player chooses so it would overwrite the current conditions of the button. Would this not work? Is there a way of doing it?

Comment: You're calling the function: `function("white", playerNumber)`. So  the argument has to be a function that takes those two arguments. `topLeft()` is a function like that.

Comment: @Barmar but when in ```topLeft()``` the command calls ```playerCheck()``` with the argument of its own name (which in the code in the post has ```topL``` instead of ```topLeft```, which is a mistake) so shouldn't that treat ```function("white", playerNumber)``` as ```topLeft("white", playerNumber)```?

Comment: You need to declare `global turn` inside `gameStart()`.  Also you need to update `turn` inside `playCheck()`.

Answer (score 2):

The argument to `playerCheck()` is a button, not a function. You should change the button's text and color, not try to call it.

```
def playerCheck(button):
    global turn
    button['text'] = turn
    button['fg'] = "white"
    if turn == Player1:
        turn = Player2
    else:
        turn = Player1
```